# Echo selected values from an associate array

Tags: php, associative-array

i dont want to echo the last two values in an associative array, couldn's figure it out, please help.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
echo $value;
}
```

This echoes all the values, i want to echo all but the last 2.

Answer (score 0):

It should work to slice the array before you loop it.

```
<?php
    $newArray = array_slice( $_POST, 0, count($_POST)-2);
    foreach( $newArray AS $key => $value ) {
        echo $value;
    }
```

If you want to keep your $key value, then set the 4th parameter to true to "preserve keys":

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Maybe this is just an exercise, but I do want to note, in addition, that relying on the exact order of your POST'd elements sounds like a bad design idea that could lead to future problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just count the loops and dont print the value in the last two loops.

```
$i = 0;

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $i++; 

  if($i != count($_POST) && $i != count($_POST)-1) {
    echo $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `if($i != count($_POST) && $i != count($_POST)-1) `you could also do `if($i < count($_POST)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather do this:

```
$a = array('a' => 'q','s' => 'w','d' => 'e','f' => 'r');
$arr_count = count($a) - 2;
$i = 1;

foreach($a as $k => $val){
echo $k.' - '.$val.PHP_EOL;
if ($i == $arr_count) break;
$i++;
}
```

Comment: How does this access values in an associative array? It looks like you just access $a without even trying to specify a particular element of the array...

Comment: Sorry for that, I've updated this answer. Thanks for telling me!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution:

```
<?php

$tot=count($_POST)-2;
while ($tot--) {
  // you can also retrieve the key using key($_POST);
  echo current($_POST);
  next($_POST);
}
```